# page scroll if mouse on bottom or top jquery

Tags: jquery

How to scroll page to top and bottom when mouse moves bottom or top based on content

```
$(document).ready(function(){
myscroll = $('#myDiv');
myscroll.scrollTop(myscroll.get(0).scrollHeight);
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'based on content'?

Comment: height of html document or div which contains page data.

Answer (score 0):

Please see if [this solution](https://jsfiddle.net/ygko3j7a/) does what you expect. The idea was basically to get the mouse's Y coordinate inside the div (`mousePositionY`). If the user's mouse is inside the first 5 pixels at the `div`'s top (you can change 5 pixels to another value changing `topRegionSize`'s value - same for `bottomRegionSize`) the `div` is scrolled to top. If the mouse is inside the last 5 pixels, the `div` is scrolled to bottom.

Comment: almost same but expected same thing in  browser scroller.

Comment: Using this same code changing `#test` with `html` should work. The idea is always the same.